# Homosexuality sin or not?

Tags: homosexuality

Should Muslims treat homosexuals differently and Is there anything in the Quran that says it's okay to be homosexual?For example everyone should be treated equally...

Comment: For Quranic references see: http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/25818/549

Comment: In my opinion, the popular maxim "hate the sin, not the sinner," sums up the attitude Muslims should have.

Answer (score 4):

Homosexually has clearly been denounced in the Quran in strongest words. See the following verses:

> We sent Lot, who said to his people, "How can you commit an
>   **abomination** such as no one in the world has ever done before you? You
>   lust after men rather than women! You **transgress** all bounds!" [7:80-81]

and

> And tell of Lot. He said to his people, "Will you commit **evil**
>   knowingly? Must you go lustfully to men instead of women? Indeed, you
>   are a people who are deeply ignorant." [27:54-55]

The bold words above leave no doubt in it being a sin.

Answer (score -1):

It's a sin in most religions. Christianity, Islam, Catholicism, etc. It is a big sin in Islam. It is said that you will go to Hell if you are gay. It is stated in the Quran that you should treat everyone kindly. Therefore, you should treat gays kindly too. I don't mind gays, for I do have quite a few gay friends.

Comment: This is not true, it is not a sin to be Gay but Just to practice it.