# Why Jannah promises young handsome boys to serve and fulfill desires?

Tags: jannah, homosexuality

During the Sodoma and Gomorrah story, we know that the angels went to Lut house as young handsome boys and not in their natural form. That's why we suppose homosexuality is a sin. But why in Qur'an it's written that in Jannah we will find young handsome boys and beautiful girls that will serve you and will fulfill your desires? Isn't that a bit contradictory? How can handsome boys be a promise if homosexuality is a sin? Don’t try to answer by saying that boys are promised to girls because it's kinda clear that Qur'an almost always addresses to men.

Comment: For starters, worldly moral rules don't apply on Jannah as such. Secondly, to extrapolate the existence of young boys to imply homosexuality is your fancy.

Answer (score 6):

The handsome young boys in *Jannah* are for servicing food and drinks, not for providing means of committing homosexual acts. But let's start with the assumption that the messengers sent to Lot were young and handsome boys. The verse says:

> وَلَقَدْ جَاءَتْ رُسُلُنَا إِبْرَاهِيمَ بِالْبُشْرَىٰ قَالُوا سَلَامًا ۖ قَالَ سَلَامٌ ۖ فَمَا لَبِثَ أَن جَاءَ بِعِجْلٍ حَنِيذٍ فَلَمَّا رَأَىٰ أَيْدِيَهُمْ لَا تَصِلُ إِلَيْهِ نَكِرَهُمْ وَأَوْجَسَ مِنْهُمْ خِيفَةً ۚ قَالُوا لَا تَخَفْ إِنَّا أُرْسِلْنَا إِلَىٰ قَوْمِ لُوطٍ
>
> And certainly did Our messengers come to Abraham with good tidings; they said, "Peace." He said, "Peace," and did not delay in bringing [them] a roasted calf. But when he saw their hands not reaching for it, he distrusted them and felt from them apprehension. They said, "Fear not. We have been sent to the people of Lot."
>
> <sub>— [Surat Hud 11:69-70](https://quran.com/11/69-70)</sub>

There is no textual evidence as a verse in the Qur'an or a hadith of the Prophet ﷺ that provides the description or the number of the messengers sent to the people of Lot. There are unattributed athars of Ibn 'Abbas saying they were three, Ibn Mihsan saying they were four, Ibn Ka'b saying they were seven, Ad-Dahhāk saying they were nine, As-Suddi saying they were eleven, and Muqātil saying they were twelve. In [Tafsīr Ibn Kathīr](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=785&bk_no=49&flag=1) of these verses, he quoted As-Suddi saying that the messengers sent to the people of Lot were in the form of young men (Arabic: لما بعث الله الملائكة لقوم لوط أقبلت تمشي في صور رجال شبان حتى نزلوا على إبراهيم فتضيفوه). It is actually not known, contrary to what you mentioned, that during the Sodoma and Gomorrah story the angels were in the form of young handsome boys.

As for the Qur'an saying that in *Jannah*, we will find young handsome boys and beautiful girls that will serve and will fulfill our desires, I presume that you are referring to these verses (since the question does not mention explicitly which verses):

> وَيَطُوفُ عَلَيْهِمْ غِلْمَانٌ لَّهُمْ كَأَنَّهُمْ لُؤْلُؤٌ مَّكْنُونٌ
>
> There will circulate among them [servant] boys [especially] for them, as if they were pearls well-protected.
>
> <sub>— [Surat At-Tur 52:24](https://quran.com/52/24)</sub>
>
> ---
>
> يَطُوفُ عَلَيْهِمْ وِلْدَانٌ مُّخَلَّدُونَ بِأَكْوَابٍ وَأَبَارِيقَ وَكَأْسٍ مِّن مَّعِينٍ
>
> There will circulate among them young boys made eternal with vessels, pitchers, and a cup [of wine] from a flowing spring.
>
> <sub>— [Surat Al-Waqi'ah 56:17-18](https://quran.com/56/17-18)</sub>
>
> ---
>
> وَيَطُوفُ عَلَيْهِمْ وِلْدَانٌ مُّخَلَّدُونَ إِذَا رَأَيْتَهُمْ حَسِبْتَهُمْ لُؤْلُؤًا مَّنثُورًا
>
> There will circulate among them young boys made eternal. When you see them, you would think them [as beautiful as] scattered pearls.
>
> <sub>— [Surat Al-Insan 76:19](https://quran.com/76/19/)</sub>

First, there is only a mention of young boys; there is no mention of young girls in any of the verses that describe the servants in *Jannah*.

Second, there is no known interpretation of the verses above (or any other verses for that matter) that said boys are promised to girls. Hence, you will find no prominent scholar that will attempt or have attempted to defend this [Straw man fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straw_man) by claiming so.

Third, there is nothing in the verses that allude that the purpose of the young boys is homosexuality. This is somewhat an [association fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_fallacy). Not because in this world some people perform homosexual acts with young boys that automatically young boys in *Jannah* will be there for practicing homosexuality. The purpose is service is mentioned in [Qur'an 56:17-21](https://quran.com/56/17-21): "There will circulate among them young boys made eternal with vessels, pitchers and a cup [of wine] from a flowing spring — no headache will they have therefrom, nor will they be intoxicated — and fruit of what they select and the meat of fowl, from whatever they desire."

Fourth, all major interpretations of the Qur'an agree that the young boys provide service by moving around quickly to bring the dwellers of *Jannah* the food and drinks they desire. For instance, [Al-Qurtubi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Qurtubi) in his tafsīr ([Al-Jāmi' li Ahkām al-Qur'an](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=3651&bk_no=48&flag=1)) said the young boys are for the service of the dwellers of *Jannah*, and that they move about quickly and provide service promptly. [At-Tabari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Tabari) in his tafsīr ([Tafsīr At-Tabari](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=4994&bk_no=50&flag=1)) said that the young boys are there to serve the people of *Jannah*, and that each one of them [the people of *Jannah*] will have a thousand young boys according to 'Abdullah ibn 'Amr, all active in their service. [Ibn Kathir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Kathir) in his tafsīr ([Tafsīr al-Qur'an al-'Adhīm](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/katheer/sura76-aya19.html#katheer)) said the young boys going around the *Jannah* are to serve the dwellers of *Jannah*.

In conclusion, it is quite evident in Islam that homosexuality is not permitted. There is no supposition that homosexuality is a sin; it is definite and has an associated ruling:

> عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم: مَنْ وَجَدْتُمُوهُ يَعْمَلُ عَمَلَ قَوْمِ لُوطٍ فَاقْتُلُوا الْفَاعِلَ وَالْمَفْعُولَ بِهِ
>
> Narrated Abdullah ibn Abbas: The Prophet (ﷺ) said: If you find anyone doing as Lot's people did, kill the one who does it, and the one to whom it is done.
>
> <sub>— [Sunan Abi Dawud, Book 40, Hadith 112](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/40/112)</sub>

The Qur'an described the people of Lot as transgressors ([26:165-166](https://quran.com/26/165-166/)) and ignorant ([27:55](https://quran.com/27/54)). The act of homosexuality is described as immoral:

> وَلُوطًا إِذْ قَالَ لِقَوْمِهِ أَتَأْتُونَ الْفَاحِشَةَ وَأَنتُمْ تُبْصِرُونَ
>
> And [mention] Lot, when he said to his people, "Do you commit immorality while you are seeing?
>
> <sub>— [Surat An-Naml 27:54](https://quran.com/27/54)</sub>

You may refer to the following questions for more information on the topic of homosexuality:

- [What does Islam say about homosexuality?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/449/8393)
- [What does the Quran say about homosexuality?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/1452/8393)
- [If homosexuality should result in execution, why is it not listed in ahadith as a reason to kill someone?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/40471/8393)
- [Homosexuality sin or not?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/20271/8393)

You may hear some arguments that what is not permissible in this world may become permissible in the hereafter. This is true; however, this statement is out of context regarding these verses. What becomes permissible in the hereafter are things that have both beneficial and harmful aspects in this world (e.g., wine as per [2:219](https://quran.com/2/219)) with the harmful aspect getting eliminated in the hereafter (e.g., no bad effects and no intoxication as per [37:47](https://quran.com/37/47/)). The act of homosexuality, being immoral and a major sin, will not be permitted in *Jannah* as no sin is permitted there:

> لَا يَسْمَعُونَ فِيهَا لَغْوًا وَلَا تَأْثِيمًا
>
> They will not hear therein ill speech or commission of sin.
>
> <sub>— [Surat Al-Waqi'ah 56:25](https://quran.com/56/25/)</sub>

You may want to refer, for additional information, to this question on Islam Q&A about
[refuting the fabrication of the liars who say that the immortal youths (in Paradise) are created for homosexuals](https://islamqa.info/en/174691).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, in regard to your claim that said

> During the sodoma and gomorra story we know that the angels went to
>   Lut house as young handsome boys and not in their natural form. That's
>   why we suppose homosexuality is a sin.

Both of Sunni and Shia considered homosexuality as a haram practice according to the holy Qur'an and hadiths (traditions).

---

In regard to your ultimate question concerning:

> Isn't that a bit contradictory? How can handsome boys be a promise if
>   homosexuality is a Sin?

For example, if it is considered as a right matter as you explained (that Allah will give us… as it is haram in this world), it can be justified by declaring that Allah has made us many things as haram things in this world in order to test us. Actually he has made many items haram as if they are motivating the lust and in fact the human lust is going toward that. Thus Allah would test us if we can prevent ourselves against the lust or not. In other word, Allah would examine us if we obey his orders or not.

So, there are some things which are considered as haram things in this world (which Allah made them forbidden solely in this world such as Alcohol, wine…), but apparently they will be halal in the paradise (Jannah) as much as I know. For instance there could be many things which are permissible in a place and are not permissible in another places. Such as:

- You can use and read all of your school's books at your home as a
  permissible act, but you cannot use them during your exam. Then we
  cannot say that "if it is permissible for us to read our books, then
  why it is impermissible to read them when we are at the exam
  meeting?! The answer is that because it is the exam, and we should
  listen to our teacher (lord)

  ---

**Conclusion (briefly):**

Allah could made them halal in this world, but he would test us who obey or not, then he will give us (as reward) what we are interested in (with best qualities…). We ought to be aware that: as a rational issue, testing human can be related to the acts which we are interested in (based on our lusts), but the scores would be based on who obeyed or not.

---

**References:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa8945)
- [www.jonbeshnet.ir](http://www.jonbeshnet.ir/news/50081)

Answer (score 0):

fulfill your desires= homosexuality
U make this up. It is not written in Quran.
Yes it is written that they will serve you. But where it is written that they will fulfill ur desires?
Please let me know !
For some people may be desires means only sex.

If father look at his son, or look at the son of his brother or look at his nephew or look at street boy with love and praise his beauty and complexion  ! Would the father be a gay? Obviously not. Love and likeness not always means lust.

Lust is just a state of mind. It is a temporary state. Not a constant way of life.
How you are sure that lust will be present in heaven or not?
And even if it is how you make up "fulfill your desires= homosexuality"?

On qoura forum:
Why would there be beautiful boys to serve men in paradise according to the Quran? Isn't that homosexuality?

1- The dear questioner is in a doubt, about the purification of heaven dwellers, by asking the last question that “Isn't that homosexuality?” to explain more I should say, the Holy Quran has repeatedly mentioned, paradise is a place without any impurity and uncleanness. I draw your attention to two verses:

يَغْفِرْ لَكمُ‏ْ ذُنُوبَكمُ‏ْ وَ يُدْخِلْكمُ‏ْ جَنَّاتٍ تجَرِى مِن تحَتهِا الْأَنهْارُ وَ

مَسَاكِنَ طَيِّبَةً فىِ جَنَّاتِ عَدْنٍ ذَالِكَ الْفَوْزُ الْعَظِيمُ(صف/12)

He shall forgive you your sins and admit you into gardens with streams running in them, and into good dwellings in the Gardens of Eden. That is the great success.

لا يَسْمَعُونَ فيها لَغْواً وَ لا تَأْثيماً (واقعه/25)

They will not hear any unnecessary or sinful talks.

As the verses show, heaven dwellers live in pure lodgings. Also they will not hear any sinful talks and because homosexuality is an impure and major sin, so certainly there is nothing in the paradise like homosexuality.

2- Let me explain a little about following verse:

وَ يَطُوفُ عَلَيْهِمْ غِلْمانٌ لَهُمْ كَأَنَّهُمْ لُؤْلُؤٌ مَكْنُونٌ (طور/24)

And round them shall go boys of theirs as if they were hidden pearls (52:24)

This verse has described the boys who serve as servants in the Heaven. The verse shows that the heaven dwellers will place in a great position in the paradise. Naturally their servants also are not like ordinary people, rather they are like hidden pearls in terms of cleanness and beauty. Outward aspects of the verse show that handsome boys have created just for serving in the paradise and the verse doesn’t imply the sexual pleasure. As a result, the doubt of sodomy doesn’t exist.

Answer (score 0):

It has been reported from the Prophet saww when asked about the children of the Polytheists, said: ‘They will be the servants of the inhabitants of Paradise.’  (مجمعِ البيان9ِ:327.)

Al-Tabarsy, regarding the meaning of eternal youths [56:17], from Ali asws: ‘These are the children of the people of the world who never had any good deeds they could be Rewarded for, and no sins which they could be Punished for.They would be descended to this status. (مجمعِ البيان9ِ:327.)

Answer (score 0):

jannah's life is different from this life. I don't know if Gelman will be served there to do sex with in jannah. but even if they will, it does not mean anything to support homosexuality for this life. for example, in jannah, people will drink hard drinks. but taking hard drink is absolutely haram in this life.

In jannah drinking hard drinks won't be considered as crime or bad practice , but its a super crime in duniya's life.
According to the same logic, may be, I dont know, in jannah, having homosex with the gelman won't be considered as crime or bad practice, but its super crime in duniya's life.